# String have a value when add it to dictionary give me no summary?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am not expert in objective c 
when add value to string and add it to dictionary give me no summary?

[image]

lcountry have a value "Egypt"

[image]

but in dictionary give me no summary

Comment: You really should replace all those calls to `setValue:forKey:` with `setObject:forKey:`. It's not related to your issue but only use key-value coding when you have a specific need to do so.

Comment: thanks so much i will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it

NSString* dsd = [NSString stringWithString:lcountry];

Comment: Likely you get rid of a tagged pointer by doing so. But this is not an advantage, because tagged pointers are for performance optimization. However, what is the original problem? Every representation of an object in lldb is done by the result of `-debugDescription`. This applies to dictionaries, too. `-debugDescription` can simply use `-debugDescription` of the contained object, what might make the description of the dictionary being illegible, if the description is very long. Likeliy it tries to optimize it and fails doing so, when it is an instance of `NSTaggedPointerString`. File a bug.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try doing something like:

```
[PostOb setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.locationCity forKey:@"LocationCity"]];
```

Comment: if it direct string will work the problem is NSTaggedPointerString

Comment: @MOMMH lol didnt see that oops.. well if he plans on it being a string could he not do

`[PostOb setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.locationCity forKey:@"LocationCity"]];`